# Throw Error in function taking escaping closure

Tags: swift, escaping, closures, try-catch, throw

I am trying to write a custom function that registers a new user in Firebase. I have imported Firebase in a class named DatabaseManager. There, I manage all database interaction. In this class I would like to have a custom function for adding users, that throws all Firebase errors. This is so i can use the function in a ViewController class where I can catch the errors and show alerts. 
However I cannot seem to get the function to work properly and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here's my function:

```
enum createAccountError : Error{
        case emailInUse, weakPassword, networkError, unknownError
    }

    //Mark: create a user profile
    ///create account with email, password, username, phoneNumber, birthDate, name
    func createAccount(_ userModel: UserModel, _ password: String?, completion: @escaping (_ inner: ()throws -> Bool)->())  {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: userModel.email!, password: password!, completion: {(user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code) {
                    switch errCode {
                    case .emailAlreadyInUse:
                        completion({throw createAccountError.emailInUse})
                    case .weakPassword:
                        completion({throw createAccountError.weakPassword})
                    case .networkError:
                        completion({throw createAccountError.networkError})
                    default:
                        completion({throw createAccountError.unknownError})
                    }
                }
                return
            } else {
                completion({return true})
            }
        })
    }
```

and here's how I have tried using it:

```
DatabaseManager.system.createAccount(user, password) { (( inner: ()throws -> Bool)->()) in
            do{
                let result = try inner()
            } catch .emailInUse{
                //show alert
            }
            }
```

Comment: Please update your question (don't post comments) to clearly explain what issues you are having with the code you posted.

Comment: maddy, not sure what you mean, all i am asking is how to use a function. The way I am using it does not work.

Comment: "does not work" is not a useful statement. In what way doesn't it work exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created test function for demonstration and everything works properly

```swift
// error type
enum TestError: Error { case notFound, empty }
// define typealias for eiser usage of complex function type
typealias ThrowableCallback = () throws -> Bool

func createAccount(_ shouldThrow: Bool, completion: @escaping (_ inner: ThrowableCallback) -> Void) {
  // call completion callback asynchronously
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if shouldThrow {
      // throw error
      completion({ throw TestError.notFound })
    }
    // return value
    completion({ return true })
  }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
createAccount(true) { (inner: ThrowableCallback) -> Void in
        do {
          let success = try inner()
          print(success)
        } catch {
          print(error)
        }
      }
```

UPD: I don't recommend using this technique for handling errors in asynchronous functions. Use separate callbacks for success and failure or Promises to gracefully handle asynchronous code (check [this](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) out for more info)

UPD 2: Actual Solution

```swift
typealias ThrowableCallback = () throws -> User 
func createAccount(_ userModel: UserModel,
                   _ password: String,
                   completion: @escaping (_ inner: ThrowableCallback) -> Void) {
  Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: userModel.email!, password: password!, completion: {(user, error) in 
    if let error = error { completion({ throw error }) } 
    else { completions({ return user! }) } 
  }) 
}

// usage
createAccount(userModel, somePassword) { (inner: ThrowableCallback) -> Void in
        do {
          let createdUser = try inner()
        } catch {
          ler errCode = (error as NSError)._code
          switch errCode {
             case .emailAlreadyInUse:
               showAlert("Email is already in use")
             case .weakPassword:
               showAlert("please enter stronger password ")
             case .networkError:
               showAlert("it seams that there is no internet connection")
             default:
               showAlert("Error creating user. Please try again later")
             }
        }
      }
```

Comment: i like your solution. regarding you advice of not using it, see the whole reason I am doing this is because i would like to handle Firebase errors in a different class where I'll be using this function createAccount(). To be honest, relooking at my code I think that generating more enums out of the switch cases might not be the best approach, but I am not sure how to transfer the out the AuthErrorCode error. So that I can handle it in other classes. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: Nice, that looks great. I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Andy C, so I actually have a problem in your code. When using it, line let errCode = (error as NSError)._code, the error type is actually  AuthErrorCode. So the problem is that I cannot carry that over in the class I'm planing to use the function. What would be a fix for that?

Comment: @dre_84w934 Sorry i forget about this. You should convert it into  AuthErrorCode type by using this code `let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: (error as NSError)._code)`. Then everything should work properly.

Comment: oh, you're fast, thanks. I see, so then I gotta import Firebase in the class I'm planning to use the createAccount() right?. I don't see any other way.

Comment: yes, you are right,and this is the easiest part :) Let me know if this solution is good for you and I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest refactoring your function as follows:

```
func createAccount(_ userModel: UserModel, _ password: String?, completion: @escaping(Error?) -> ())  {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: userModel.email!, password: password!, completion: {(user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code) {
                switch errCode {
                case .emailAlreadyInUse:
                    completion(createAccountError.emailInUse)
                case .weakPassword:
                    completion(createAccountError.weakPassword)
                case .networkError:
                    completion(createAccountError.networkError)
                default:
                    completion(createAccountError.unknownError)
                }
            }

        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    })
}
```

Then when you call the function you can check if there was an error like this:

```
DatabaseManager.system.createAccount(user, password) { (error) in
   guard error == nil else {
      //Handle error
      return
   }

   //There was no error
```